# How to align duplicates on the same rows in Excel in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, formulas

Here is my situation..

I have this file :

```
   1004    Dr  Margarita Solorzano Olabarria    SILVER  228230185    
   1004    Mr  Jose Manuel Santos Aboim Inglez  BRONZE  236338858    
   1007    Mrs  Amanda De Souza Rodrigues       BRONZE  238246729    
   1007    Mr  Eduardo Jaime Smejoff            BRONZE  214046768    
   1010    Mrs  Genevieve Thie                  PLATIN  221093078   
   1010    Mrs  Mary Wilson                     PLPLUS  21384102    
   1203    Ms  Valerie Harrison                 BRONZE  207754414    
   1203    Ms  Joy Bridget Moncrieff            BRONZE  207754415
```

with In Column A : Cabin Number

Column B: Mr or Mrs

Column C: First & Last Name

Column D: Status (bronze, silver etc...)

Column E: Membership number

If Column A are the same I want it on the same row. but it Excludes Status Bronze, Silver,Gold,
So I put this in my VBA to exclude those :

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[1]=R[-1]C[1],RC[3]=""SILVER"", RC[3]=""BRONZE"", RC[3]=""GOLD""),""Delete"", """")"
```

When I run the macros it gaves me this :

```
1211    Mr  Thomas Buettner PLPLUS  Mr  Heinz Juergen Nolte PLPLUS
4011    Mr  Michael Brent   PLATIN  Mrs  Wilhelmina Johanna PLATIN
4013    Mrs  Nancy Jean     PLATIN  Mr  James               PLATIN
4034    Mr  Donald  Meyer   PLATIN  Mrs  Marcia  Meyer      PLATIN
1010    Mrs  Genevieve Thie PLATIN  
1010    Mrs  Mary Wilson    PLPLUS
```

Look at the Number 1010..

Somehow Both are in the condition but because they have different status, the macro put them in a different row and I don't want that, I want them in the same row..

Can you help me..

Added on Mar 7th, Here is My whole Macro (I don't want an another Sub) :

```
Sub LATDownloadMACROS()
'
' LATDownloadMACROS Macro
' Macro recorded 02/25/2017 by Johan Esteve


' Debut Macro
Cells.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("D:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns("C:C").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Columns("E:E").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = "=PROPER(RC[-3])&"" ""&PROPER(RC[-1])&"" ""&PROPER(RC[-2])"
Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E4200"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("E2:E4200").Select
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("B:D").Select
Range("D1").Activate

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("B18").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets.Add
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Download"
Sheets("Download").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Cells.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B1").Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Guest 1"
Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "Level1"
Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "Guest 2"
Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "Level2"
Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "Guest 3"
Range("G1").FormulaR1C1 = "Level3"
Range("F1:G1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("F1:M1"), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "Guest 2"
Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]=R[-1]C[-3],RC[-2],"""")"
Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-4]=R[-1]C[-4],RC[-2],"""")"
Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[1]C[-3]=RC[-3],R[1]C[-2],"""")"
Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[1]C[-4]=RC[-4],R[1]C[-2],"""")"
Range("F2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[2]C[-5]=RC[-5],R[2]C[-4],"""")"
Range("G2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[2]C[-6]=RC[-6],R[2]C[-4],"""")"
Range("H2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[3]C[-7]=RC[-7],R[3]C[-6],"""")"
Range("I2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[3]C[-8]=RC[-8],R[3]C[-6],"""")"
Range("J2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[4]C[-9]=RC[-9],R[4]C[-8],"""")"
Range("K2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[4]C[-10]=RC[-10],R[4]C[-8],"""")"
Range("L2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[5]C[-11]=RC[-11],R[5]C[-10],"""")"
Range("M2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[5]C[-12]=RC[-12],R[5]C[-10],"""")"
Range("D2:M2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:M4200"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("D2:M4200").Select

Columns("D:M").AutoFit
Sheets("Sheet2").Move Before:=Sheets(1)

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Sheets("Sheet2").Copy Before:=Sheets(2)
Sheets("Sheet2 (2)").Select
Range("D2").Select
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Columns("D:M").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Columns("A:A").Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[1]=R[-1]C[1],""Delete"", """")"
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A6"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A6").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A4200"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A4200").Select
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Cells.Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

Sheets("Sheet2 (2)").Select
Columns("A:C").Sort Key1:=Range("C2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Key2:=Range("A2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=if"
Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[1]=R[-1]C[1],RC[3]=""BRONZE"",RC[3]=""SILVER""),""Delete"","""")"

Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A4200"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A4200").Select

Columns("A:A").Select
Sheets("Sheet2 (2)").Select
Sheets.Add
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Sheets("Sheet4").Move After:=Sheets(3)
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "Champagne"
Sheets("Sheet2 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet2 (2)").Name = "Water"
Columns("E:N").Copy

Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Range("D1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D2").Select
Sheets("Water").Select
Cells.Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("B2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Sheets("Download").Select
Selection.Copy
Columns("A:C").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Columns("A:C").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

' Ambassador
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("C2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Key2:=Range("A2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = ""
Range("A2").Select
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Sheets("Sheet4").Copy Before:=Sheets(3)
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Move After:=Sheets(4)
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Sheets("Sheet4").Name = "Ambassador"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[1]=R[-1]C[1],RC[3]=""SILVER"", RC[3]=""BRONZE"", RC[3]=""GOLD"",RC[3]=""PLATIN"",RC[3]=""PLPLUS""),""Delete"", """")"
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A4200"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A4200").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("Ambassador").Select
Rows("2:4200").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Ambassador").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Ambassador").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "A2:A4200"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Ambassador").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "B2:B4200"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortTextAsNumbers
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Ambassador").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A2:O4200")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Rows("1:1").Select

 ' Chocolate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Key2:=Range("C2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=Range("A2"), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers, DataOption3:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = ""
Range("A2").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Copy Before:=Sheets(3)
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Move After:=Sheets(4)
Sheets("Sheet4 (3)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (3)").Name = "ChocoStrawb"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[1]=R[-1]C[1],RC[3]=""SILVER"", RC[3]=""BRONZE"", RC[3]=""GOLD""),""Delete"", """")"
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A4200"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A4200").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("ChocoStrawb").Select
Rows("2:4200").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ChocoStrawb").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ChocoStrawb").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "A2:A4200"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ChocoStrawb").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "B2:B4200"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortTextAsNumbers
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ChocoStrawb").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A2:O4200")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Rows("1:1").Select

' PlatinumPlus
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("D2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=Range("B2"), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, DataOption3:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = ""
Range("A2").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Copy Before:=Sheets(3)
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Move After:=Sheets(4)
Sheets("Sheet4 (3)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (3)").Name = "PlatPlus"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[1]=R[-1]C[1],RC[3]=""SILVER"", RC[3]=""BRONZE"", RC[3]=""GOLD"",RC[3]=""PLATIN"",RC[3]=""AMBASS""),""Delete"", """")"
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A4200"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A4200").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

' Platinum
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("D2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=Range("B2"), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, DataOption3:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = ""
Range("A2").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Copy Before:=Sheets(3)
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Move After:=Sheets(4)
Sheets("Sheet4 (3)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (3)").Name = "Platinum"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[1]=R[-1]C[1],RC[3]=""SILVER"", RC[3]=""BRONZE"", RC[3]=""GOLD"",RC[3]=""PLPLUS"",RC[3]=""AMBASS""),""Delete"", """")"
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A4200"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A4200").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

 ' Gold
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("E2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=Range("B2"), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, DataOption3:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Range("C6").Select
Range("C496:C4288").Select
Range("C4288:C16").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Copy Before:=Sheets(5)
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (2)").Name = "Gold"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[1]=R[-1]C[1],RC[3]=""SILVER"", RC[3]=""BRONZE"", RC[3]=""PLATIN"",RC[3]=""PLPLUS"",RC[3]=""AMBASS""),""Delete"", """")"
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A4200"), Type:=xlFillDefault
' Rajout
Range("A2:A4200").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

' Silver

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Key2:=Range("B2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Cells.Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("B2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Range("C13").Select
Sheets("Platinum").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("B2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Range("C7").Select
Sheets("Gold").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (3)").Select
Sheets("Sheet4 (3)").Name = "Silver"
Sheets("Silver").Select
Sheets("Silver").Copy Before:=Sheets(6)
Sheets("Silver").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[1]=R[-1]C[1],RC[3]=""PLATIN"", RC[3]=""BRONZE"", RC[3]=""GOLD"",RC[3]=""PLPLUS"",RC[3]=""AMBASS""),""Delete"", """")"
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A4200"), Type:=xlFillDefault

Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Cells.Select

' Bronze

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Key2:=Range("B2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Cells.Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("B2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
Sheets("Silver (2)").Select
Columns("B:D").Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("D2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(RC[1]=R[-1]C[1],RC[3]=""SILVER"", RC[3]=""PLATIN"", RC[3]=""GOLD"",RC[3]=""PLPLUS"",RC[3]=""AMBASS""),""Delete"", """")"
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A519"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A519").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A4200"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A4200").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Cells.Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("B2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False _
    , Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers

' Nomage C1
Sheets("Champagne").Select
Range("C1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Ambassador").Select
Range("C1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("PlatPlus").Select
Range("D1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("ChocoStrawb").Select
Range("D1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Ambassador").Select
Range("D1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Platinum").Select
Range("C1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Gold").Select
Range("C1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Silver").Select
Range("C1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Silver (2)").Select
Range("C1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

' Nomage Bronze
Sheets("Silver (2)").Select
Sheets("Silver (2)").Name = "Bronze"
Range("A1").Select

Sheets("Champagne").Select
Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
Range("A1").Select

 ' Filtre et Figer
Sheets("Champagne").Select
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("C2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("Platinum").Select
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("C2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("PlatPlus").Select
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("C2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("Silver").Select
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("C2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("Bronze").Select
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("C2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("Gold").Select
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("C2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("ChocoStrawb").Select
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("C2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("Water").Select
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("C2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("Ambassador").Select
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("C2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("Download").Select
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("A2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter

' Color
Sheets("Champagne").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Champagne").Tab.ColorIndex = 6
Sheets("Platinum").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Platinum").Tab.ColorIndex = 16
Sheets("PlatPlus").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PlatPlus").Tab.ColorIndex = 55
Sheets("Silver").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Silver").Tab.ColorIndex = 15
Sheets("Bronze").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Bronze").Tab.ColorIndex = 9
Sheets("Gold").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Gold").Tab.ColorIndex = 43
Sheets("ChocoStrawb").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ChocoStrawb").Tab.ColorIndex = 3
Sheets("Water").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Water").Tab.ColorIndex = 2
Sheets("Ambassador").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Ambassador").Tab.ColorIndex = 1
Sheets("Download").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Download").Tab.ColorIndex = 4

' Delete

Dim WS As Worksheet

For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
For x = 4200 To 2 Step -1
    If WS.Cells(x, 1).Value = "Delete" Then
        WS.Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next x
Next WS


' Formulas

Sheets("Water").Select
Cells.Select
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(D2:N2)+((COUNTIF(D2:N2,""GOLD"")+COUNTIF(D2:N2,""PLATIN""))*1)+((COUNTIF(D2:N2,""PLPLUS"")+COUNTIF(D2:N2,""AMBASS""))*2)"
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
LastRow = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
Cells(LastRow + 2, "A").Formula = "=SUM(A2:A" & LastRow & ")"
Dim LRowA As String, LRowB As String
LRowA = [A4200].End(xlUp).Address
Range("A:A").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Range("A2:" & LRowA).Interior.ColorIndex = 33
Range("A:A").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter



' Classement Onglets
Sheets("Water").Select
Sheets("Water").Move Before:=Sheets(2)
Sheets("ChocoStrawb").Select
Sheets("ChocoStrawb").Move Before:=Sheets(3)
Sheets("Bronze").Select
Sheets("Bronze").Move Before:=Sheets(4)
Sheets("Silver").Select
Sheets("Silver").Move Before:=Sheets(5)
Sheets("Gold").Select
Sheets("Gold").Move Before:=Sheets(6)
Sheets("Champagne").Select
End Sub
```

This My Whole Code.. Now Under 'Chocolate sheets and 'water sheets I want the same cabin on the same row if they are valid for the condition even do they are different status.

Comment: It's very hard to help you with just a single line of your code to look at.  (Especially when that piece of code refers to something 3 columns to the right of the ActiveCell which, depending on what the ActiveCell was, would mean in column D or later but your data appears to have the information in column C.)  Please paste the rest of the code into the question so that we can help you.

Comment: @YowE3K, I edited my question Can you have a look please

Comment: Normally I would consider it fun to accept the challenge to tidy up your code so that I could understand it enough to work out what is wrong, but your requirement to handle everything in one subroutine (rather than breaking the code down into smaller chunks so that it is easier to manage) means I'm not even going to think about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your data are:

- in worksheet named after "mySheetName"
- in columns from A to D
- with first row as a "header" one
- with all records sharing the same "code" in a *contiguous* range

then you could use:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim code As Variant

    With Sheets("mySheetName") '<--| change "mySheetName" to your actual sheet name
        With .Range("D1", .cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its columns A:D range from row 1 (header) down to the one corresponding to last column A not empty row
            DeleteSilverAndBronzeRecords .cells '<--| delete all records with "SILVER" or "BRONZE" in columnn "C"
            For Each code In GetCodes(.Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1)) '<-- loop through unique "codes" starting from 2nd row downwards
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.cells, code) > 1 Then HandleCodes .cells, code '<--| if more then one current 'code' occurrences then "handle" it
            Next
        End With
    End With
End Sub


Sub DeleteSilverAndBronzeRecords(rng As Range)
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array("GOLD", "SILVER", "BRONZE"), Operator:=xlFilterValues '<--| filter column C cells with "GOLD", "SILVER" or "BRONZE"
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any filtered cell other than headers
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete '<-- delete filtered cells, skipping headers
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub

Sub HandleCodes(rng As Range, code As Variant)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim iCell As Long, refvalue As Long
    Dim strng As String

    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=code '<--| filter column A cells with current 'code'
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<-- reference filtered cells, skipping headers
                For Each cell In .cells '<--| loop through filtered cells
                    strng = strng & Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(cell.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 2).Value)), " ") & " " '<--| build concatenated string from all current 'code' records
                Next
                .cells(1, 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(strng) '<--| write updated column "B" content in first record with current "code"
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).Delete '<--| delete all current "code" occurrences from the 2nd one on
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End With
        End If
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub

Function GetCodes(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim cell As Range
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each cell In rng
            .Item(cell.Value) = cell.Value
        Next cell
        GetCodes = .keys
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: @JohanEs, did you get through it?

Comment: Changing a question after you received solution to the _original_ one leads to what's been called "chamaleon" questions, which are not allowed here. Please, take your time to give proper feedback to answers received after your _original_ question and accept them if they solved it or specify why they didin't. Once this phase is over you may want to ask for additional issues or post a new question altogheher

Comment: @user33598756 sorry about the editing.. I did so because of your answer that does not go on my macro.. that's why I edited the question because your answer may be correct.. but it does not fit in my macro... that's why I came back to you and said that I edited my question so you can review your answer... Because your answer does not work in my micro it says ERROR... Again sorry about the misunderstanding...

Comment: Why don't you simply try adjusting my code in those few parts as per comments guiding you and run it by itself?

Comment: DeleteSilverAndBronze for example it does not take it... I don't know anything about macro.. I didn't take any curse it is my first time I see a macro but I need to do it for my job....

Comment: Put all those subs and function in any module (you can keep all them in a same module)  and then run "Main". It'll call all other subs/functions when needed. You can step through the code by placing your cursor in any statement inside Main() and pressing F8: this will yellow highlight the first statement to be executed and by pressing F8 you have it executed and jump to the following, and so on. at any time you can switch to Excel UI to see what's going at every statement execution

Answer (score 0):

In excel --- Home---Conditional formatting ---highlight cell rules----duplicate values--- (Select your range and do) Let me know in case you need more

Comment: Won't that just highlight duplicates?

Comment: It will highlight test now and based on color just sort

Comment: It's very hard to sort multiple rows into a single row. (Which I **think** is what the OP is trying to do - but they haven't really said what problem they are having - I'm not sure whether the second set of data in the question is "desired" output or "current" output which isn't matching "desired" in some way.)